# VB.NET Access SQL syntax error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to perform an `INSERT` query into an access database with VB.NET, and it keeps complaining that I have a syntax error. I can't seem to figure it out though. If I run it in Access itself, it works.

To give you a glimpse of what is happening, here is some debugging code :

```
Dim params(6) As OleDb.OleDbParameter
    params(0) = New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@matchNumber", Integer.Parse(recMatchNumber))
    params(1) = New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@teamNumber", Integer.Parse(recTeamNumber))
    params(2) = New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@action", recAction)
    params(3) = New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@object", recObject)
    params(4) = New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@level", recLevel)
    params(5) = New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@location", recLocation)
    params(6) = New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@time", recTime)

For Each param As OleDb.OleDbParameter In params
        Console.WriteLine(command.CommandText)
        Console.WriteLine(param.ParameterName)
        Console.WriteLine(param.Value)
        command.Parameters.Add(param)
Next
```

And here is the result :

```
INSERT INTO matchData( matchNumber, teamNumber, action, object, [level], location, [time]) VALUES(@matchNumber,@teamNumber,@action,@object,@level,@location,@time)
@matchNumber
1
INSERT INTO matchData( matchNumber, teamNumber, action, object, [level], location, [time]) VALUES(@matchNumber,@teamNumber,@action,@object,@level,@location,@time)
@teamNumber
50
INSERT INTO matchData( matchNumber, teamNumber, action, object, [level], location, [time]) VALUES(@matchNumber,@teamNumber,@action,@object,@level,@location,@time)
@action
Move
INSERT INTO matchData( matchNumber, teamNumber, action, object, [level], location, [time]) VALUES(@matchNumber,@teamNumber,@action,@object,@level,@location,@time)
@object
Robot
INSERT INTO matchData( matchNumber, teamNumber, action, object, [level], location, [time]) VALUES(@matchNumber,@teamNumber,@action,@object,@level,@location,@time)
@level
0
INSERT INTO matchData( matchNumber, teamNumber, action, object, [level], location, [time]) VALUES(@matchNumber,@teamNumber,@action,@object,@level,@location,@time)
@location
Zone
INSERT INTO matchData( matchNumber, teamNumber, action, object, [level], location, [time]) VALUES(@matchNumber,@teamNumber,@action,@object,@level,@location,@time)
@time
Auto
```

The error is `Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.`

Thanks.

Comment: I bet `object` is a keyword.  Put it in brackets. If it's not too late, I would change that field name to something more descriptive.

Comment: `action` and `object` are both [reserved words](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html)

Comment: [Access reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe)

Comment: Great, that worked. Thanks! If you would like to add an answer, I'd be glad to accept it. @HansUp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was commented, object and action are reserved words, so you would have to place brackets around those names: [object], [action], etc.

See [Access 2007 reserved words and symbols](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe) for the entire list of reserved words.

Some common reserved words I often see causing problems:

- action
- date
- object
- password
- user

It's usually better to avoid using those words as the names of your database fields.